# Start Krusader in a directory from command line

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, krusader

I want to start krusader from terminal in directory `/tmp` in left panel.

how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:~$ krusader --help

Usage: krusader [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [options] url 

Krusader
Twin-Panel File Manager for KDE

Generic options:
  --help                    Show help about options
  --help-qt                 Show Qt specific options
  --help-kde                Show KDE specific options
  --help-all                Show all options
  --author                  Show author information
  -v, --version             Show version information
  --license                 Show license information
  --                        End of options

Options:
  --left <path>             Start left panel at <path>
  --right <path>            Start right panel at <path>
  --profile <panel-profile> Load this profile on startup

Arguments:
  url                       Url to open
```

Comment: lol :D I did try man, but I forgot about help :D there is no man for krusader on my machine.